# Avoid Where phrase with gorm

Tags: mysql, go, grails-orm

I'm trying to update every record in a table:

```
sqlDB.Table("task").Where("1=1").Update("status", 1)
```

And I can't avoid the `1=1` where condition. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the big default of gorm, I think this is the only way to do it using Table().Update(). Otherwise you can simply execute the full update command as a string.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois Table().Update() prompts me "No where condition is set"

Comment: Yes you can't do that, this syntax only works in gorm if you have an object in Table(&obj) and it automatically adds a where clause with the value of the primary key(s). This is a bit stupid but it is like that. I'd use something like go-pg or its successor uptrace/bun if I were you, you'd have much more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `1=1` is a widely recognized always-true WHERE clause. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Block-Global-Updates

This should work:

```
db.Session(&gorm.Session{AllowGlobalUpdate: true}).Model(&User{}).Update("name", "jinzhu")
```